# Query document against multiple words

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 6.x version with ingest plugin to let me query inside document.
I managed to insert record with attachment document and I'm able to query it against various fields.

When I query the content of the file I'm doing this:

```
 boolQuery.filter(new MatchPhrasePrefixQueryBuilder("attachment.content", "St. Anna Church"))
```

It works, but I want now to make query with this field: "Church Wall People" where basically it's not a complete phrase, I want back all the documents that contain the words Church, Wall and People.

Comment: You can use three match queries wrapped inside must clause of a book query

Comment: thanks it makes sense, I thought that could be a particular query class to do such things